# file type association error

Tags: macros, cmd.exe, file-association

i keep my `doskey` macros in a separate file with `.macro` file extension, and can load them using `doskey /macrofile=macros.macro` for the specific console session

i want to use windows os feature of file type association to load them without having to type the command (the executable's name or path) every time

for that reason i use two built-in `cmd.exe` commands:

```
assoc .macro=macro
ftype macro="doskey /macrofile=%1"
```

there's no error, but when i execute the file pop-up message appears, and basically it doesn't work

previously i tried to associate `.reg` files with `reg import %1` and it worked, the problem here seems to be the equals sign in `doskey`'s `/macrofile=` switch, i think the system can't handle it

i think, despite switches (`/`) and subcommands after the executable name can work with parameters, but `=` somehow fails to do so

so i'm asking for solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ftype` splits its argument on "=" and provides no means to escape the second "=" character in the command. Fortunately this command just adds a simple registry setting, which you can add manually using `reg` in an elevated command prompt:

```
assoc .macro=macrofile
set k=HKLM\Software\Classes\macrofile\shell\open\command
set d="\"%SystemRoot%\system32\doskey.exe\" /macrofile=\"%1\""
reg add %k% /f /ve /d %d%
```

Or create a .reg file that can be imported with `regedit` or `reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\.macro]
@="macrofile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\macrofile]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\macrofile\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\macrofile\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\macrofile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\doskey.exe\" /macrofile=\"%1\""
```

Example:

```
C:\>assoc .macro
.macro=macrofile
C:\>ftype macrofile
macrofile="C:\Windows\system32\doskey.exe" /macrofile="%1"

C:\>doskey /macros:all
[cmd.exe]

C:\>spam.macro
C:\>doskey /macros:all
[cmd.exe]
    spam=echo spam!

C:\>spam
spam!
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason it doesn't add the `%1` part in the data field leaving the quotes empty, i added it manually in `regedit`, and if possible could you implement it in a `reg` file, it would be easier to import to the registry in a such way, i tried to do it but with no success (data didn't get added)

Comment: The `reg` command I used gave exactly the result that I showed in the example via `ftype macrofile`, so it works fine for me in Windows 7. Are you using a different version?